# Is there an infinite group that has finite subgroup with finite index?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

> Is there an infinite group that has finite subgroup with finite index?

I can find one, if the index is infinite - but what if the index is finite?

Thanks

Comment: But... isn't the cardinality of the group the product of cardinality and index of the subgroup?

Comment: Better questions would have been: "Is there an infinite group that has an infinite subgroup with finite index?" or "Is there an infinite group that has a finite subgroup with infinite index?" or "Is there an infinite group that has an infinite subgroup with infinite index?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. If $H$ is a finite subgroup of finite index in a group $G$, then $\left| G\right| = \left| H\right|[G:H]$ is finite.